# How would I make a player invisible only to certain players?

Tags: lua, roblox

Basically what I've done so far is add a boolValue to every player, and if that boolValue is set to true, they can see invisible people, if it is false, they can't. I am clueless about the code currently so I have no idea how to begin. I'm also changing the value of the Bool Value through a tool.

Comment: You should post some code next time.

Comment: but i don't actually know where to start, that's the problem.

Comment: Yes, but you said
`Basically what I've done so far is add a boolValue to every player`
Show that code to help us.

Answer (score 3):

The key to making one player invisible only to certain players is the understanding that  any changes made to the world in a [LocalScript](https://developer.roblox.com/en-us/api-reference/class/LocalScript) are only visible to that player. They are not replicated between other clients. So, if we can set up a system where LocalScripts can be told to turn a specific player invisible, that player will vanish from their screen and their screen only.

So if we had that system, Player Two could say, "Hey game server, could you let the people know to turn me invisible!". That message would go up to the server, the server would send it out to a bunch of different clients, and each client would make the change locally using their LocalScripts, and the player would effectively turn invisible on their screen.

[image: Image is of 3 different views into the game world where Player Two is invisible. The first view is from Player One's perspective, Player One sees only Player Three. The second view is from Player Two's perspective, Player Two's character is transparent and sees both Player One and Three. The final view is from Player Three's perspective, and Player Three only sees Player One.]

So even though Player Two looks to be invisible to Players One and Three, to the game server, nothing is different or out of the ordinary, the changes are localized entirely to each player's version of the world.

[image: Image of the game server's perspective of the world. All three players are visible.]

One way to do this is to use a setup like this :

[image: Example of Workspace]

- A [Tool](https://developer.roblox.com/en-us/api-reference/class/Tool) in [StarterPack](https://developer.roblox.com/en-us/api-reference/class/StarterPack) to allow players to control their visibility
- A [BoolValue](https://developer.roblox.com/en-us/api-reference/class/BoolValue) inside that tool to hold onto the visiblity state
- A [LocalScript](https://developer.roblox.com/en-us/api-reference/class/LocalScript) to control the tool's logic
- A [RemoteEvent](https://developer.roblox.com/en-us/api-reference/class/RemoteEvent) in [ReplicatedStorage](https://developer.roblox.com/en-us/api-reference/class/ReplicatedStorage)
- A [Script](https://developer.roblox.com/en-us/api-reference/class/Script) in [ServerScriptService](https://developer.roblox.com/en-us/api-reference/class/ServerScriptService) to handle the event routing

In the LocalScript, you would have something like this :

```
local tool = script.Parent
local IsHidden = tool:WaitForChild("IsHidden", 5)
local TogglePlayerVisible = game.ReplicatedStorage.TogglePlayerVisible
local localPlayer = game.Players.LocalPlayer

-- debug
tool.Name = "Turn Invisible"
tool.RequiresHandle = false
IsHidden.Value = false

-- 1) When a player activates the tool, flip the BoolValue
tool.Activated:Connect(function()
    IsHidden.Value = not IsHidden.Value
    tool.Name = IsHidden.Value and "Become Visible" or "Turn Invisible"
end)

-- 2) When the BoolValue changes, tell the server about it
IsHidden.Changed:Connect(function(updatedValue)
    TogglePlayerVisible:FireServer(updatedValue)    
end)

-- 4) When the server tells us a player has used the tool, make that player invisible locally
TogglePlayerVisible.OnClientEvent:Connect(function(player, isHidden)
    local invisible = 1.0
    local visible = 0.0
    
    -- if we are the one who sent it, only make us a little invisible
    if (player.Name == localPlayer.Name) then
        invisible = 0.7
    end
    
    -- loop over all of the parts in a player's Character Model and hide them
    for _, part in ipairs(player.Character:GetDescendants()) do
        local shouldTogglePart = true
        
        -- handle exceptions
        if not (part:IsA("BasePart") or part:IsA("Decal")) then
            shouldTogglePart = false
        elseif part.Name == "HumanoidRootPart" then
            shouldTogglePart = false
        end
        
        -- hide or show all the parts and decals
        if shouldTogglePart then
            part.Transparency = isHidden and invisible or visible
        end
    end
end)
```

And in the Script, you would have something like this :

```
local TogglePlayerVisible = game.ReplicatedStorage.TogglePlayerVisible

-- 3) whenever a player triggers this event, send it out to all players
TogglePlayerVisible.OnServerEvent:Connect(function(player, isVisible)
    TogglePlayerVisible:FireAllClients(player, isVisible)
end)
```

If you would like only *specific* players to not see a player, then you can modify step 3 so that instead of using `TogglePlayerVisible:FireAllClients`, you would specifically choose which players to send the message to using [FireClient](https://developer.roblox.com/en-us/api-reference/function/RemoteEvent/FireClient).

Comment: hi, thanks! this is super helpful! one thing though, how would i make invisible players see other invisible players?

Comment: In Step 3, we send the message out to players to show or hide a player using `TogglePlayerVisible`. So I would modify Step 3, and have the server Script keep track of all the players who are invisible, adding invisible players to a table, and removing visible ones. Whenever a player becomes invisible, I would loop over my list of players and tell only the newly invisible player to make everyone visible again... Or at least partially, so you can tell who is supposed to be invisible.