# How would I make it so that players are only half invisible to a players in a certain team/in a certain group?

Tags: scripting, roblox

I was following the example in this question [How would I make a player invisible only to certain players?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65554921/how-would-i-make-a-player-invisible-only-to-certain-players), but I can't adapt it to my needs.

How would I make it so that players are only half invisible to a players in a certain team/in a certain group? And how do I make it so that fellow invisible players see invisible players?

Answer (score 0):

Building on the code from the previous code sample, to make this work you only have to modify the last step where the server tells all of the clients to show or hide the players.

Since you are trying to satisfy two conditions :

1. Teammates can be seen, even when invisible, and
2. Invisible players can be seen when the you are also invisible

You need to add some conditions to keep track of what team people are on and who is actively invisible. When one of your teammates turns invisible, we only partially hide them. And when we, the local player, turn invisible we need to iterate over all of the hidden players and reveal them.

That code might look like this :

```
-- make a helper function to reveal / hide a player
local function setVisiblity(player, isHidden, showPartial)
    local invisible = 1.0
    local visible = 0.0

    -- if showing partially, make invisibility slightly more visible
    if (showPartial == true) then
        invisible = 0.7
    end

    -- loop over all of the parts in a player's Character Model and hide them
    for _, part in ipairs(player.Character:GetDescendants()) do
        local shouldTogglePart = true
    
        -- handle exceptions
        if not (part:IsA("BasePart") or part:IsA("Decal")) then
            shouldTogglePart = false
        elseif part.Name == "HumanoidRootPart" then
            shouldTogglePart = false
        end
    
        -- hide or show all the parts and decals
        if shouldTogglePart then
            part.Transparency = isHidden and invisible or visible
        end
    end
end

-- make a table to hold onto the hidden players
local invisiblePlayers = {} -- <playerName, playerObject>

TogglePlayerVisible.OnClientEvent:Connect(function(player, isHidden)
    -- flip the visibility of the player that requested the change
    local showPartial = false

    -- keep track of who is visible / invisible
    if (isHidden) then
        invisiblePlayers[player.Name] = player
    else
        invisiblePlayers[player.Name] = nil
    end

    -- reveal the invisible players if it is you
    if (player.Name == localPlayer.Name)
        showPartial = true

        -- if we are now invisible, reveal all the other invisible players, otherwise hide them
        local canSeeOtherInvisibleUnits = false
        if (isHidden) then
            canSeeOtherInvisibleUnits = true
        end

        -- loop over the invisible players and reveal or hide them
        for name, invisPlayer in pairs(invisiblePlayers) do
            setVisible(player, canSeeOtherInvisibleUnits, true)
        end

    -- reveal the other player if we're on the same team
    elseif (player.TeamColor == localPlayer.TeamColor)
        showPartial = true

    -- reveal the other player if we are currently invisible
    elseif (invisiblePlayers[localPlayer.Name] ~= nil)
        showPartial = true
    end

    -- toggle that player's invisibility
    setVisiblity(player, isHidden, showPartial)
end)
```