# How do I check this in Roblox?

Tags: lua, roblox

I am making an invisibility potion in Roblox. My goal is to make it so that you can somewhat see your character locally, but everyone else in the server (not including you) can't see you at all.

So far it's going well, locally, I've set the transparency to 0.7, but the server part is the problem, every time I've tried to make the server detect if it was dealing with the player or other players. it just seemed to never work.

With the current scripts I have now, it will work, but only if you double click it, and I just want it to not get confused but just work as intended.

These are my two current scripts, local and server.
Local:

```lua
local UIS = game:GetService("UserInputService")
script.Parent.Activated:Connect(function()
    UIS.InputBegan:Connect(function(input, gpe)
        if input.UserInputType == Enum.UserInputType.MouseButton1 then
            local Player = script.Parent.Parent
            script.Parent.EnableEvent:FireServer()
            for _, child in ipairs(Player:GetChildren()) do
                if child:IsA("BasePart") then
                    if child.Name == "HumanoidRootPart" then
                        child.Transparency = 1
                    else
                        child.Transparency = 0.7
                    end
                elseif child:IsA("Accessory") then
                    child.Handle.Transparency = 0.7
                end
            end
            wait(20)
            for _, child in ipairs(Player:GetChildren()) do
                if child:IsA("BasePart") then
                    if child.Name == "HumanoidRootPart" then
                        child.Transparency = 1
                    else
                        child.Transparency = 0
                    end
                elseif child:IsA("Accessory") then
                    child.Handle.Transparency = 0
                end
            end
        end
    end)
end)
```

And server:

```lua
script.Parent.EnableEvent.OnServerEvent:Connect(function(player, Name)
    local Player = script.Parent.Parent
    if Name ~= script.Parent.Parent.Name then
        for _, child in ipairs(Player:GetChildren()) do
            if child:IsA("BasePart") then
                child.Transparency = 1
            elseif child:IsA("Accessory") then
                child.Handle.Transparency = 1
            end
        end
        wait(20)
        for _, child in ipairs(Player:GetChildren()) do
            if child:IsA("BasePart") then
                if child.Name == "HumanoidRootPart" then
                    child.Transparency = 1
                else
                    child.Transparency = 0
                end
            elseif child:IsA("Accessory") then
                child.Handle.Transparency = 0
            end
        end
    end
end)
```

And the end result looks like this:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/fqj6P.jpg

Comment: Similar question here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65554921/how-would-i-make-a-player-invisible-only-to-certain-players/65556671#65556671

Answer (score 1):

Before I dive into a solution, here's an explanation of what's going on.

Simply when you fire a remote event, it doesn't immediately execute (due to delay between the client and server) So the client is making everything .7 transparency, first and then the server overrides that and makes everything fully transparent. The reason why the second click makes everything fully transparent is because on the server you're already at transparency 1.

1. Player Transparency is set to .7
2. Server Transparency is set to 1 transparency and overriding the local transparency

-- Second click

3. Player Transparency is set to .7
4. Server Transparency is already 1 so it doesn't change it.
   (Leaving you with transparency .7 after the second click)

---

So in order to solve this problem we just need to wait for the server to change the transparency first, then the local player should change their transparency to .7 after. My recommendation is to use a [remote function](https://developer.roblox.com/en-us/api-reference/class/RemoteFunction) instead of a remote event.

Unlike a remote event, a remote function acts like a function and when called needs complete/return before continuing the script.

```lua
-- Example
-- server
local remoteFunction = game.ReplicatedStorage.RemoteFunction
remoteFunction.OnServerInvoke = function(player)
    wait(5)
end

-- client
local remoteFunction = game.ReplicatedStorage.RemoteFunction

remoteFunction:InvokeServer()
print("Hello World") -- is delayed by 5 seconds since the function call needs to finish
```

---

So yeah, you should be able to just change your code to a remote function and that should hopefully solve your problem!